# Google maps does not show pointer

Tags: android, google-maps

I am sending coordinates to google maps and it shows me map  of desired location. But it does not show pointer to exact location by given coordinates. What should I change?

```
geoUriString = "geo:"+co+"?z=15";
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
                        Intent map = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
                        startActivity(map);
```

where `co` is - `50.444906, 30.531149`

Comment: What does the value of `co` look like?

Comment: co is 50.444906, 30.531149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a pointer, if I'm not mistaken, you have to add it as a query:

```
"geo:"+co+"?q="+co;
```

Something like this.